# OpenERP v7: Need to show only journals that are not in the same period

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

So I have made some invoices in which the "invoice date" does not match the "accounting period". In a journal you have option to check the dates but that isn't right now important.

What I need to do is a tree view which shows entries that accounting period is not in the same month as invoice date. How would I do it? I researched filters but I am not sure how I could make so complex filters. Another thing I saw was SQL queries but again I am not sure how I could attach the data to tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
    _columns = {
    'is_period_difference': fields.function(_period_difference, 
                                            string='Period Difference', 
                                            type='boolean',
                                            store=True)
```

where _period_difference is my function that calculates true or false.